# How to hide node title while in edit without automatic nodetitle module?

Tags: 6, nodes

Actually in hook nodeapi(op:presave) I'm setting my own custom title so I want to hide the title field from the node edit form.

It does not work if I use automatic nodetitle module since it is also changing the title.

What is the best way to hide the title without using automatic nodetitle module?

Answer (score 2):

Use hook_form_alter and unset($form['title']) in a custom module (since the node create / edit form will usually be displayed in your admin theme this will be a better approach than adding the function to your themes template.php file.

So create a module with a basic mymodule.info file.

Create a mymodule.module file and add:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

   // 1.NODE TYPE FORM
   if ($form_id == 'NODE_CONTENT_TYPE_node_form') {
     unset($form['title'];
   }

 }
```